# How open video MP4?

Tags: c#

how open video in axWindowsMediaPlayer1.

I have created the code for the picturebox.
What is code for axWindowsMediaPlayer1?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "JPEG| *.jpg", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false })
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                obrazekPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `axWindowsMediaPlayer1`?

Comment: [AxWindowsMediaPlayer.URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562470(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: http://imgur.com/OcIDQal

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use picturebox or anything. Just drag and drop the mediaplayer control and you are good to go. Use this code to run a video:

```
 axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = ofd.FileName;
 axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

Comment: https://youtu.be/uONQaT-nwls?t=14m12s Is possible using axWindowsMediaPlayer1 for display videos ...as picturebox for display images

Comment: Then you need to use some other library like Aforge.NET or FFMPEG wrappers to divide videos into frames and show them in picture box one by one.